# Syntax error beyond end of program

Tags: ocaml

I am experimenting with writing a toy compiler in ocaml.  Currently, I am trying to implement the [offside rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule) for my lexer.  However, I am having some trouble with the ocaml syntax (the compiler errors are extremely un-informative).  The code below (33 lines of it) causes an error on line 34, beyond the end of the source code.  I am unsure what is causing this error.

```
open Printf

let s = (Stack.create():int Stack.t);

let rec check x =
    (
        if Stack.is_empty s then
            Stack.push x s
        else if Stack.top s < x then
            (
                Stack.push x s;
                printf "INDENT\n";
            )
        else if Stack.top s > x then
            (
                printf "DEDENT\n";
                Stack.pop s;
                check x;
            )
        else
            printf "MATCHED\n";
     );

let main () =
    (
        check 0;
        check 4;
        check 6;
        check 8;
        check 5;
    );

let _ = Printexc.print main ()
```

Ocaml output:

```
File "lexer.ml", line 34, characters 0-0:
Error: Syntax error
```

Can someone help me work out what the error is caused by and help me on my way to fixing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trailing **;** after the definitions of *main*, *check* and *s* are erroneous.

Replace these 3 occurences with **;;** as follows:

```
let s = (Stack.create():int Stack.t);;

let rec check x =
  (
      (* ...sequence of imperative statements... *)
  );;

let main () =
  (
      (* ...sequence of imperative statements... *)
  );;
```

**;** is used in the following cases:

- to sequence imperative statements
- as a separator between list elements
- as a separator between array elements
- as a separator between record fields

Some examples:

```
let hello_world1 () =
  print_endline "Hello";
  print_endline "World !"
;;

let hello_world2 () =
  begin
    print_endline "Hello";
    print_endline "World !"
  end
;;

let hello_world3 () =
  (
    print_endline "Hello";
    print_endline "World !";
  )
;;

let some_list =
  [1; 2; 3]
;;

let some_array =
  [| 'a'; 'b'; 'c' |]
;;

type my_process =
  {
    pid: int;
    executable_path: string;
  }
;;

let p1 = { pid = 142; executable_path = "./my_exec" };;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, and also for clearing up for me where I should / should not use the single semi-colon.

Comment: although in this particular case, all of those double-semicolons are optional, since your file is all definitions. only when you have a bare statement at the top level, are you required to have a double-semicolon before it

Comment: I still like using the double-semis for noob examples because otherwise it can be confusing. OCaml's semicolon rules are easily the most confusing part of the language IMO, followed by the slashdot operators.

Comment: I *think* I understand the slashdot operators, but those semi-colon rules keep tripping me up.  I figured at first that double semi-colons after every statement, function call, etc. would work, but it turns out I need to put even more effort into it :-/

Comment: a_m0d; you should put less effort into it. Just avoid semicolons expect when dealing with imperative statements, and dealing with the toplevel (even imperative statements can avoid semicolon use, `let () = ... in`).

Comment: I am experimenting with ocaml, and encountered same problem. thx for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the `;` works:

```
open Printf

let (s:int Stack.t) = Stack.create() 

let rec check x =
    (
        if Stack.is_empty s then
            Stack.push x s
        else if Stack.top s < x then
            (
                Stack.push x s;
                printf "INDENT\n";
            )
        else if Stack.top s > x then
            (
                printf "DEDENT\n";
                Stack.pop s;
                check x;
            )
        else
            printf "MATCHED\n";
     )  

let main () =
    (
        check 0;
        check 4;
        check 6;
        check 8;
        check 5;
    ) 

let _ = 
  Printexc.print main ()
```

Running it:

```
gaius@debian:~/Projects/TestCase$ ./lexer 
INDENT
INDENT
INDENT
DEDENT
DEDENT
INDENT
```

Comment: How could you not mention your blog post on the subject? (I'm sure in response to this, no?) http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/ocaml-compiler-errors/

Comment: Actually I found this question while researching that post :-)